# Iterate all values in nested json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to iterate all the values of nested json but am running into the problem of how to do it. What I have is https://jsfiddle.net/wjaw7pyw/

But I am unsure of how to loop where I currently have result[0]. The json is structured as like the following

```
{
  "foo": {
    "result": [
      {
        "test" : 1
        "test2" : 2
        "test3" : 3
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate through bar as

```
 <li ng-repeat="x in myData.foo.bar">

 </li>
```

if you also want to iterate through results you can use nested ng-repeats

```
<div ng-repeat="results in myData">
    <div ng-repeat="item in results ">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help